# Can I retrieve information from Google Maps' app while mine is running on background?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, background, gps

I need to build a turn-by-turn navigation on my app, but since they don't allow it using Google Maps API (Usage Terms 10.4.c), I was thinking about letting my app running on background and Google Maps on top of it, running the turn-by-turn navigation. But I need to retrieve information from it, like when the user reaches the next step of the navigation.

Are there any ways to do this?